# $1-\frac{\ln(a+b)}{3}\le \int^1_0 (a+b)^{-x^2}\,dx \le \frac{\arctan(\sqrt{\ln(a+b)})}{\sqrt{\ln(a+b))}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, definite-integrals

Let $a$ and $b$ real numbers such that $a >1/2 , b >1/2$. Prove that :
$1-\frac{\ln(a+b)}{3}\le \int^1_0 (a+b)^{-x^2}\,dx \le \frac{\arctan(\sqrt{\ln(a+b)})}{\sqrt{\ln(a+b)}}$
I tried to apply the Mean value theorem but I did not get to any result.

Comment: Just want to double check that you meant for the inequalities to face opposite directions. Often people write $a<b<c$ and you have $a<b>c$.

Comment: Use \ before math functions. For example, write `\arctan(\sqrt{a})` for $\arctan(\sqrt{a})$ instead of `arctan(sqrt(a))` which produces $arctan(sqrt(a))$.

Comment: Alright. Thank you! I am sorry for the writing mistakes.

Comment: Both inequalities should follow from the “well-known” estimates  $1+x\le e^x \le \frac{1}{1-x}$.

Comment: Why do you think it?

Comment: Write $(a+b)^{-x} = e^{-x^2 \ln(a+b)} \ge 1-x^2 \ln (a+b)$ and see what happens ...

Comment: Ok!Thank you! @MartinR

Answer (score 1):

$(a+b)^{-x^2} = e^{-x^2 \ln(a+b)}$, and $1+u\le e^u \le \frac{1}{1-u}$ holds for all real $u < 1$, so that
$$
 1 - x^2 \ln (a+b) \le (a+b)^{-x^2} \le \frac{1}{1+x^2 \ln(a+b)}
$$
for $0 \le x \le 1$. Now integrate over $[0, 1]$ to get the desired inequalities.

Comment: Its ingenious to use $a^x=e^{x\ln a}$ +1

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore: Actually it is quite natural if you need to estimate $a^x$ :)

Comment: maybe for people like you ,but  it is not obvious!is it?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore: It depends on from where you come. For non-rational (real or complex) exponents that is how $a^x$ is *defined.*

Comment: I am just a student ,and i guess i have to learn more ....:)